# CheckedListBox docking not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I created a user control for Windows forms application. All it has is a TableLayoutPanel with four cells. Cell[0,0] and cell[0,1] have labels. Cell[1,0] has a treeview and cell[1,1] has CheckedListBox.

For all four controls, I have set docking to Fill. That freaking CheckedListBox appears smaller than TreeView. Is there any way to get proper docking for the controls?

BTW, I am using .Net 3.5 and VS 2010.

Following is the designer file code for the control:

```
namespace UserControls
{
    partial class LinkedContent
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.lblContentGroups = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.lblModules = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.tvContent = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
            this.chkListBoxModules = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.lblContentGroups, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.lblModules, 1, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.tvContent, 0, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.chkListBoxModules, 1, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 7.760532F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 92.23947F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(501, 451);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lblContentGroups
            // 
            this.lblContentGroups.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblContentGroups.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.lblContentGroups.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 1);
            this.lblContentGroups.Name = "lblContentGroups";
            this.lblContentGroups.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(243, 34);
            this.lblContentGroups.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblContentGroups.Text = "Content Groups";
            this.lblContentGroups.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // lblModules
            // 
            this.lblModules.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblModules.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.lblModules.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(254, 1);
            this.lblModules.Name = "lblModules";
            this.lblModules.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(243, 34);
            this.lblModules.TabIndex = 1;
            this.lblModules.Text = "Modules";
            this.lblModules.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // tvContent
            // 
            this.tvContent.CheckBoxes = true;
            this.tvContent.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tvContent.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 39);
            this.tvContent.Name = "tvContent";
            this.tvContent.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(243, 408);
            this.tvContent.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // chkListBoxModules
            // 
            this.chkListBoxModules.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.chkListBoxModules.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.chkListBoxModules.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(254, 39);
            this.chkListBoxModules.Name = "chkListBoxModules";
            this.chkListBoxModules.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(243, 408);
            this.chkListBoxModules.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // LinkedContent
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.Name = "LinkedContent";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(501, 451);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblContentGroups;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblModules;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView tvContent;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox chkListBoxModules;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a screenshot up to show us what it looks like?

Comment: with the given information i was not able to reproduce the described behaviour. pls provide us with some code and a screenshot - thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check to make sure the [IntegralHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.integralheight.aspx) Property is not set. It defaults to true.

From above MSDN Link:

> When this property is set to true, the control automatically resizes
>   to ensure that an item is not partially displayed. If you want to
>   maintain the original size of the ListBox based on the space
>   requirements of your form, set this property to false.